# TypeScript type definition for custom module pattern

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a type definition for a custom built module specification I've inherited here. Cannot figure it out. The trick is that the *this* context in the computed context in *functions* should be driven from *properties* such that *shouldBeValueA* is driven from *keyA*.

```
define.model("moduleName",
[
    "jquery"
],
function($) {
    return this.viewModel({
        pub: {
            properties: {
                keyA: "valueA"
            },
            functions: {
                keyB: this.computed(function() {
                    var shouldBeValueA = this.keyA;
                })
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Best definition I've got so far:

```
interface Define {
model: (
    name: string,
    dependencies: string[],
    moduleContext: <T>(this: {
        computed: (context: (this: T) => any) => KnockoutComputed<any>,
        viewModel: (options: {
            pub: {
                properties: T,
                functions: any
            },
        }) => any;
    },
    ...args) => void) => void;
}

declare var define: Define;
```

But this errors: "Property keyA does not exist on type T"

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do this myself, but Vue.js has a similar API, and it might help to look at [their type definitions](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/types) for reference

Comment: This is a tricky one. I think the inner call to `this.viewModel()` is preventing the type `T` from being inferred "upward". I played with this in the Playground a bit and couldn't get it to work. Either `T` is inferred as `{}` or it seems to be unresolved as `T` (as your current code does). Only workaround was to define `model<T>` instead of `modelContext<T>`, then call using a type like `model<{ keyA: string }>`...

Comment: Thinking about this more today, I might need higher kinded types in typescript which are currently not supported. That is, if I define a type for the viewmodel itself I get 

`type viewModel<T> = (options: {
    pub: {
        properties: T,
        functions?: any
    },
}) => any 

interface Define {
    model: (
        name: string,
        dependencies: string[],
        moduleContext: <A, F extends viewModel<A>>(this: {
            computed: (context: (this: A) => any) => KnockoutComputed<any>,
            viewModel: F
        },
        ...args) => any) => any;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help anybody else, but @kingdaro is correct that this pattern is very similar to the vue.js API. I eventually built a type definition inspired by that pattern.

```
interface RequireDefine {
    model<TPubProps, TPubFuncs, TPrivProps, TPrivFuncs>(
        name: string,
        deps: string[],
        factory: (
            this: {
                viewModel<TPubProps, TPubFuncs, TPrivProps, TPrivFuncs>(
                    options: ThisTypedViewModelOptions<TPubProps, TPubFuncs, TPrivProps, TPrivFuncs>
                ): TPubProps & TPubFuncs
    ): any
}

type ThisTypedViewModelOptions<TPubProps, TPubFuncs, TPrivProps, TPrivFuncs> =
    object
    & ViewModelOptions<TPubProps, TPubFuncs, TPrivProps, TPrivFuncs>
    & ThisType<CombinedViewModelInstance<TPubProps, TPubFuncs, TPrivProps, TPrivFuncs>>

type CombinedViewModelInstance<TPubProps, TPubFuncs, TPrivProps, TPrivFuncs> = TPubProps & TPubFuncs & { priv: () => TPrivProps & TPrivFuncs }    

type DefaultMethods = { [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => any };

interface ViewModelOptions<
    TPubProps = object,
    TPubFuncs = DefaultMethods,
    TPrivProps = object,
    TPrivFuncs = DefaultMethods
    > {

    ctor?: (options?: any) => void,
    pub?: {
        properties?: TPubProps,
        functions?: TPubFuncs
    },
    priv?: {
        properties?: TPrivProps,
        functions?: TPrivFuncs
    }
}
```

It's still not completely perfect, but it was a good learning experience adapting the vue types to this viewmodel structure.